# How to return a PDF from a Logic App HTTP response

Tags: javascript, http, pdf, ms-word, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App with a http trigger. The app does a bunch of stuff and at the end converts a word document to PDF using the Convert Word Document to PDF action.

I am trying to return that document in the response action like this:
[image]

I am calling this Logic App from some JS code and downloading it. When I download it, the PDF is blank but the file size is not zero.

When I look at an executed run, I can see that the output of the response action like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=SiteComplianceReport.VictorDemoCompany.CGO.20230315.pdf",
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
    },
    "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/pdf",
        "$content": "JVBERi0xLjcNCi..."
    }
   }
```

If I take the long string that is the value of $content and paste it into a base64 to pdf generator online, it spits out the proper PDF.

I've tried to use `base64ToBinary(body('Convert_Word_Document_to_PDF'))` to convert the output to binary but it doesnt work because the output is an object.

I've also tried using a bunch of combinations like  `base64ToBinary(base64(string(body('Convert_Word_Document_to_PDF')))` but I cant get anything to output the PDF properly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

#### edit:

Here is the `js` function that's processing the response. Could this be modified to process the base64 response?

```
function callGenReportAPI_Native(reqBody){
    console.log("Request Body: " + reqBody);
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://MY-LA-URL";
    
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
    req.send(reqBody);
    req.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var contentDispo = e.currentTarget.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            var fileName = contentDispo.match(/filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/)[1];
            saveBlob(blob, fileName);
        }
        else{
            console.log("File download failed")
        }
    };
}

function saveBlob(blob, fileName) {
    //Create a link element, hide it, direct it towards the blob, and then 'click' it programatically
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.style = "display: none";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    //Create a DOMString representing the blob and point the link element towards it
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    //programatically click the link to trigger the download
    a.click();
    //release the reference to the file by revoking the Object URL
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Comment: Why not return it as base64?

Comment: Maybe that is the better approach, but it's the js function that needs to be modified to handle it correctly? I'll add the js function to the question

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried using a bunch of combinations like `base64ToBinary(base64(string(body('Convert_Word_Document_to_PDF')))` but I cant get anything to output the PDF properly

After reproducing from my end, I have received the same error.

[image]

This is because you are not selecting content from the body of `Convert_Word_Document_to_PDF` as the body will have both the `$content` and `$content-type` in the form of object. To get the desired results, your expression should look something like below.

```
base64ToBinary(body('Convert_Word_Document_to_PDF')['$content'])
```

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

Comment: I did try this, all it seems to do is change the `$content-type` of the object from `application/pdf` to `application/octet-stream`. The `$content` component is still the same value. Then when I pass it to the js function to download, I have the same issue with it coming in blank